# Set font-size automatically according to the element height

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, fonts, font-size

I have a text input and preview text div. I want the preview text `font size` to adjust automatically according to the given `height`. Please keep in mind, it will only see `height` to adjust its font size, `width` will be `auto`.
*I have google and researched a lot, I have also tried them but these questions/answers are different than mine.*
When i set the div height to `50px`, it should automatically adjust the `font size` according to that height, `height matters`, height should not go bigger than the given one & when text goes to next line, then it should decrement the `font size` to `fit the text` to the `height`.
**Here is the code:**

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input')
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    const self = e.currentTarget
    const size = parseInt(self.value)
    const textElem = document.querySelector('.previewText')
    textElem.style.height = `${size}px`

    adjustText(size, textElem)
})

const adjustText = (size, textElem) => {
    const childElem = textElem.firstChild.nextElementSibling
    let fontSize = textElem.style.fontSize
    fontSize = fontSize.replace('px', '')
    for (let i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (textElem.offsetHeight > childElem.offsetHeight) {
            console.log('greater tha')
            textElem.style.fontSize = `${i}px`
        }
        if (textElem.offsetHeight < childElem.offsetHeight) {
            console.log('less than')
            textElem.style.fontSize = `${fontSize - 1}px`
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="number">
<div class="previewText">
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.</div>
</div>
```

It's working almost right, but it's not working perfectly. Can someone please help me? I am stuck...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got your code right but I guess the condition in your for loop doesn't work.

You need to **decrease font-size as long as the text height is larger than it's parent div** like so:

```
    for(let i; textHeight>previewTextHeight; i++ ){}
```

#### Example snippet

(You can edit the text to check the font-size adjustment)

```js
const fontSize = document.querySelector('#fontSize');
const previewText = document.querySelector('.previewText');
const textInner = document.querySelector('.textInner');
const currentFontSize = document.querySelector('.currentFontSize');

const adjustText = function() {
  let size = fontSize.value;
  previewText.style.fontSize = `${size*1}px`;
  previewText.style.height = `${size}px`;
  let previewTextHeight = previewText.clientHeight;
  let textHeight = Math.ceil(textInner.clientHeight);

  for (let i; textHeight > previewTextHeight; i++) {
    size -= 1;
    previewText.style.fontSize = `${size*1}px`;
    textHeight = Math.ceil(textInner.clientHeight);
  }
  currentFontSize.textContent = `fontSize: ${size} height: ${previewTextHeight}`;
}

//
adjustText();

fontSize.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  adjustText()
})


textInner.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  adjustText()
});
```

```css
.previewText {
  outline: 1px solid #ccc;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.textInner:focus {
  outline: none
}
```

```html
<p>Font-size</p>
<input id="fontSize" type="range" value="200" step="10" min="10" max="200">
<p>Editable text</p>
<div class="previewText">
  <div class="textInner" contentEditable>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod.</div>
</div>
<p class="currentFontSize"></p>
```